# populate array to utiableview

Tags: ios4

How do I populate this array to uitableviewcell. I had tried this like below one but not success.

```
cell.textlabel.text = [array objectatIndex:indexpath.row];
```

so pls. guide for better solution.

```
{
        name = nick;
        surname = xyz;
        timeCreated = "2012-01-06 04:03:03 +0000";
        timeUpdated = "1999-11-30 00:00:00 +0000";
        userID = 1;
        userno = 0;
    },
        {
        name = samuel;
        surname = xyz;
        timeCreated = "2012-01-06 04:03:24 +0000";
        timeUpdated = "1999-11-30 00:00:00 +0000";
        userID = 2;
        userno = 1;
    },
        {
        name = John;
        surname = xyz;
        timeCreated = "2012-01-06 04:03:48 +0000";
        timeUpdated = "1999-11-30 00:00:00 +0000";
        userID = 3;
        userno = 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't assign the object from the array to the textlabel's text property.  Instead assign a value from within that object (which in your example looks like it might be JSON parsed into an NSDictionary)

For example:

```
cell.textlabel.text = [(NSDictionary*)[array objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: I am working on application that use kumulos api which  return array in above format. Now i want to populate all values of this array to uitablviewcell. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What is the class of the objects in the returned array?